# Cloudant : Error with running weatherreport to check cluster health

Tags: cluster-computing, cloudant

We have three node cluster setup and facing issue to run weather report command.
By looking at error, it is clear that machine from where weatherreport utility is running not able to connect to other two machines. I have checked all machines and they are accessible using fqdn. But from message it looks like it is using shortname while connecting to peer machine. So how to check from where it is taking peer machine names? So I can give a try to change them to full machine name and that might work for me.  if there is any other solution then let us know.

Error is coming as

```
['cloudant_diag17506@machine2031.domain.com'] [crit] Could not run check weatherreport_check_safe_to_rebuild on cluster node 'cloudant@machine2031'
['cloudant_diag17506@machine2031.domain.com'] [crit] Could not run check weatherreport_check_safe_to_rebuild on cluster node 'cloudant@machine2032'
['cloudant_diag17506@machine2031.domain.com'] [crit] Could not run check weatherreport_check_safe_to_rebuild on cluster node 'cloudant@machine2033'

['cloudant@machine2032.domain.com'] [crit] Rebuilding this node will leave the following shard with NO live copies: default/t_alpha e0000000-ffffffff, default/t_alpha a0000000-bfffffff, default/t_alpha 60000000-7fffffff, default/t_alpha 20000000-3fffffff, default/metrics_app e0000000-ffffffff, default/metrics_app a0000000-bfffffff, default/metrics_app 60000000-7fffffff, default/metrics_app 20000000-3fffffff
```

Comment: There was enough investigation done. And query asked was clear that from where cloundant service gets input about its peer machines. And answer is database which was having those entries so if you look at answer for this question, when we remove database and reconfigure, problem is solved.  So why this question is marked as flag that it is not investigated properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution for this problem.
It was problem that when DB was created first time, short name was used so in database it might be referring for short name to connect to other peer hosts.

Now that the Cloudant Local installation is in problematic stage, to make it consistent would be to remove all the files under /srv/cloudant/ on all database nodes. This will remove all default Cloudant databases. Then run the configure.sh script again on each node as before but now that "hostname -f" correctly outputs the fully qualified host name, then create your databases again.